# Annotation - Enforce a square using imrect

Tags: matlab, computer-vision

I have a Matlab program that asks the user to draw a rectangle around a human on the scene (I later extract that region using `imcrop`). I need to **enforce the user to draw a square**. I am using the `imrect` function, but I am unable to force a square, nor find documentation on how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems [`imrect`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imrect.html) can take a [position-constraining function](http://es.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imroi.html#imroi-setposcon) as an input argument. This function is specified as follows:

> Whenever the object is moved because
>       of a mouse drag, the constraint function is called using
>       the syntax:
>
> ```
> constrained_position = fcn(new_position)
> ```

Position is a vector of the form `[xleft ybottom width height]`.

So try this:

```
axis equal %// same sccale on both axes
axis manual %// freeze axes size 
h = imrect('PositionConstraintFcn', @(x) [x(1) x(2) min(x(3),x(4))*[1 1]])
```

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way would be to set the `setFixedAspectRatioMode` method to `true` during the rectangle creation, initially drawing a square. (Check [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imrect.html)).

Example:

```
%// Make sure it's initially a square!!
hRect = imrect(gca, [10 10 100 100]);

setFixedAspectRatioMode(hRect,1)
```

Then no matter how you change the position, it will remain a square. Note, however, that as opposed to Luis' solution the user can't specify the initial placement of the square.

Comment: This is simpler than my answer (+1). On the down side, it requires the square to be initially drawn (as opposed to the user directly drawing it)

Comment: Yes you're right @LuisMendo I overlooked that part oops I'll add that information to the answer. +1 for you as well your method is quite elegant!